# How can I access rails 2.3.x commands when rails 3 is installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, version

I'd like to play around with rails 3, but I'm still used to rails 2.3.8 so I have them both installed. Wanting to make a quick rails app to demonstrate how a plugin works, I want to run the command `rails test_app` but since I have rails 3 installed, I have to run `rails new test_app` but that will generate a rails 3 app. Is there a way around this while having rails 3 installed?

Comment: people have suggested [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) but if you are using windows, then try [pik](http://github.com/vertiginous/pik)

Comment: I'm using Linux so I guess RVM is what I want to use. I'll give it a shot when I'm home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
rails _2.1.0_ projectname
```

Inside that project all the old script/server, script/generate stuff is there for you.

Comment: thanks thats really easy and I didn't have to install anything.

Answer (score 5):

This is a perfect example of what [`rvm`](http://rvm.io/)'s [gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/) can do for you.

In a nutshell (after [installing rvm](http://rvm.io/rvm/install/)):

```
% rvm gemset create rails2
% rvm gemset use rails2
% gem install rails -v=2.3.8
```

Now your current `rails` is Rails 2!

Whenever you wish to use Rails 2 instead of Rails 3, do:

```
% rvm gemset use rails2
```

This will remain in effect for the current terminal/shell session. You can also switch back:

```
% rvm default
```

Of course you can also do the exact opposite and create a `rails3` gemset to play around with Rails 3, and leave Rails 2 installed as the default.

(Apart from having gemsets, `rvm` lets you install multiple versions of Ruby on the same system, allowing you to switch between different versions with a simple `rvm 1.9.2` or `rvm 1.8.7`.)

Answer (score 1):

use rvm http://rvm.io/

you can use different/multiple ruby version and have different gemsets for each :) enjoy!